# Can I change (unsigned) to (NSUInteger) or will it create problems?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unsigned, nsuinteger

I am a Jr Software Developer, can I just change the (unsigned) to (NSUInteger) or will to create problems later?

```
- (unsigned)retainCount
{
    return UINT_MAX;  //denotes an object that cannot be released
}
```

warning said

```
MKStoreManager.m:88:1: Conflicting return type in implementation of 'retainCount': 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') vs 'unsigned int'
```

I found a previous definition

```
- (NSUInteger)retainCount OBJC_ARC_UNAVAILABLE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method must return `NSUInteger` because that is how the `retainCount` method is defined in `NSObject`.

The error is being caused by the value you are trying to return. Instead of returning `UINT_MAX`, you should return `NSUIntegerMax`.

The underlying type for `NSUInteger` changes depending on whether building for 32 or 64 bit. Accordingly, the value of `NSUIntegerMax` also changes to match the type.

```
- (NSUInteger)retainCount
{
    return NSUIntegerMax;  //denotes an object that cannot be released
}
```